# How i get the soap structure of my WCF?

Tags: xml, wcf, xsd, webservices-client

i need integrate my application with another system, and i need to sent the web service structure, so for this i need to send a xml with the request and response message. I use some tools to do this but without any success. How i can solve this problem?

Comment: You really need to be more specific to get help in this forum. Which tool did you use? How did you use that tool? What do you mean by "without success"?

Comment: In general, you want to send them the WSDL and any referenced XML Schema files (*.xsd)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture samples of the requests to the Web service and the corresponding responses.

Use the WSDL of the Web service - if it is a SOAP one there should be a URL that returns it.

Comment: i try with fiddler and with WebServiceStudio and i can't get the message that i need to pass. I need the soap message with request and response from my wcf.

Comment: Fiddler does not show localhost traffic - maybe that's the reson why you don't see the request and responses? You should definitly be able to see the SOAP messages there